# How to get cyclical values on every foreach loop iteration

Tags: php, loops, iteration

sorry for the title but I don't know how to explain it well in few words.

I'm dealing with a php loop where I need to get particular css classes names and other stuff (such as different svg elements) at each group of 4 iteration.
This is what I need to obtain:

1. iteration 1 = class 1
2. iteration 2 = class 2
3. iteration 3 = class 3
4. iteration 4 = class 4
5. iteration 5 = **class 1**
6. iteration 6 = **class 2**
7. iteration 7 = **class 3**
8. (etc...)

Actually I'd like to post my attempt to get this, but this time I do not know where to begin (but probably I'm getting lost in a glass of water). Any suggestion or hints are more than welcome...

Comment: You're looking for the _modulo_ operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Modulo (`%`) operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) {
    $id = ($i % 4) + 1;
    $classname = "class{$id}";
    echo "$classname\n";
}
```

When you have an array of (class) names you want to use, then:

```
$classnames = ["class 1", "class 2", "class 3", "class 4"];
$n = count($classnames);

for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++) {
    $index = $i % $n;
    $classname = $classnames[$index];
    echo "$classname\n";
}
```

Comment: Hello @trincot - yep, in fact as I told I got lost in a glass of water. Thank you!
At the end I come up with the same solution using foreach (seems I can't get formatted code):

`$array = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5", "item 6", "item 7", "item 8", "item 9", "item 10", "item 11"];
$classnames = ["class 1", "class 2", "class 3", "class 4"];
$n = count($classnames);
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $a) {
$index = $i % $n;
$output = $a . '/';
$output .= $classnames[$index];
$output .= '<br>';
echo "$output\n";
$i++;
}`

Answer (score 0):

In a `foreach` loop it would be: the array index `%` 4 + 1, to get the repeating integer sequence `1,2,3,4`.
But, if you have an array of classNames in the order you want them repeated you can do something like this:

```php
$classNames = ['won','too','tree','fower'];
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

foreach( $array as $index => $value ){
    $cssClass = $classNames[$index % count($classNames)];
    
    echo $cssClass.",";
}
```

Output for the above:

```
won,too,tree,fower,won,too,tree,fower,won,
```

Anytime you whish to change that sequence you simply have to edit the `$classNames` array, nothing more.